# How to ignore "Accessibility" settings for React Native app?

Tags: react-native, accessibility, react-native-ios

When in the iOS settings I activate the "Bold Text" in "General -> Accessibility", some texts get cropped because they become larger and thus exceed their intended display area.

Also, if I enlarge all the texts in "Accessibility -> Large Text", suddenly, my app becomes completely unusable because everything is cropped in all directions, the texts take a lot of space.

However, when I enable these settings and go to applications like TikTok, Wishbones, ... I notice that they don't seem to be affected by these system changes.

Having no time to set everything up now to make my application respond to these settings, I was wondering how those applications do to "ignore" those settings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Preword

I think this is a valid question and I welcome questions like the above as that is partly how I got into accessibility (trying to work around an accessibility error instead of fixing it), but the below 'rant' will probably explain why you got the downvotes.

I also explain a way that you could fix your problem going forward in the section titled 'Proper use of allowFontScaling = false;' so I hope that is helpful to you / others.

### Why should you never do as OP asked.

For anyone who stumbles across this question in the future, please read the following before doing the above.

I understand deadlines are deadlines and sometimes you need to push the product live, and if the above is **purely to get your Minimal Viable Product to market as a short term fix** then go for it, you have to be realistic about your goals and if accessibility wasn't on your radar until the last second then the fix may take too long, but make it priority before stage 2.

However, experience tells me that if you follow the example of TikTok, a company who [deliberately suppresses disabled users videos](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-50645345), you have chosen a **very** bad role model. (I cannot comment on Wishbone as never seen it)

Now never mind the moral reasons of excluding people and disabling a feature they may require to use your App, instead let's talk numbers and lawsuits and see if we can't persuade you to add some time into the development budget to fix this.

### Market Size

> Globally, at least 2.2 billion people have a vision impairment or
> blindness, of whom at least 1 billion have a vision impairment that
> could have been prevented or has yet to be addressed.

Source: [World Health Organisation (WHO)](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/blindness-and-visual-impairment)

With a world population of 7.8 Billion, that means that up to 28% of your user base could require larger text in order to see your App clearly. (The numbers seen high the WHO published but who am I to argue with them!)

If you are disabling font scaling the odds are you also haven't considered the size of tap targets, icons, screen readers etc. so your app is probably completely useless to someone who is blind or partially sighted, as well as people who have accuracy issues (tap target size, often influenced by font-size) such as people with Parkinson's Disease or Cerebral Palsy.

Excluding a quarter of the world's population does not seem like a good idea if you want an App to grow, unless of course you are building the next TikTok and have a good marketing budget to reach the other 75% of the population.

If this is the case then ignore accessibility, unless the law in your country leaves you open to a legal nightmare.....

### Legal

Oh this one is going to be the biggest commercial reason to do this, large companies are getting battered by lawsuits in America where their websites aren't accessible, Apps are not going to be far behind.

Now I am not sure which country you are from, but depending on where you live you may actually find that your App is breaking the law.

I myself am from the UK and although the risk of a lawsuit is much lower here I am aware of at least two lawsuits being put together on behalf of people with disabilities against companies whose websites are inaccessible to blind people. We are following America and I have no doubt others will too.

Oh and legislation is in progress for the whole of Europe called the [European Accessibility Act](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32019L0882&from=EN#d1e2097-70-1), so every EU country will have the same laws soon.

### It isn't just people with disabilities.

I work on a 43" monitor positioned about a meter away. Now if Windows decided they would stop font-scaling I would have to completely change my setup as the font size would be too small and i would not be able to read anything.

I have no vision impairment, but the accessibility features built into Windows, web browsers, applications etc. really allow me to work the way I want to.

If I am on a train I often switch accessibility features on to make tap targets bigger so I can press them accurately when the train is buffeting around, contrast better (for glare from the sun so I can see the screen better) etc.

Tried the new 'dark theme' yet? Dark themes started for people who have issues with screen brightness and contrast perception problems. See that thing in front of you that you write on, [typewriters / keyboards were invented for blind people](https://history-computer.com/ModernComputer/Basis/keyboard.html) and I cannot imagine a world without my keyboard.

Accessibility = a better experience for everyone = happier customers / users = better reviews and recommendations = more customers = more profits = more development work for us devs = everybody wins.

### Proper use of `allowFontScaling = false;`

`allowFontScaling = false;` is a very useful thing to add to your toolbelt.

As OP has discovered sometimes a layout does not work when someone changes the font size in their system settings.

Obviously you should design your layout to accommodate larger text, but this will often ruin a pretty design if it hasn't been considered from the start.

Educating your design team takes time so it is often left to us as developers to fix these problems until company policy changes (which is easy to do if you point out the legal implications, directors tend to wake up when you mention multi-million pound lawsuits and a larger audience!)

Instead if you encounter the same problem as OP and there is no way to fix your layout you could do the following and still comply with [WCAG 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) and offer your users a feature they may require to comfortably use your App / Website.

1. Disable automatic font scaling as suggested in the answer given.
2. Add an accessibility settings section to your App / Website.
3. Add an option to control font size, font weight etc. there
4. If the font size / weight is adjusted to a size that does not work with your 'default' layout, enable a secondary layout that will accommodate this font size / weight. Allow up to 200% font scaling in this secondary layout (it can actually be quite fun trying to accommodate such large fonts on a small screen - requires some creativity!)

While the secondary layout may not be as nice it does at least mean that people can use your Website / App if they require a larger font size / heavier font weight. It increases your potential customer base and helps you comply with relevant laws.

### Conclusion

Put accessibility on your roadmap **today**.

If you build into your design process you won't have to resort to **terrible ideas** like disabling font scaling, ignoring accessibility errors etc. It will also save you a lot of effort later trying to reverse-engineer your App / Website in order to accommodate features that people **need**.

If you are near the end of development like OP, add it to your development plans as a priority item going forward to increase the number of potential users of your App and to avoid legal issues.

/End Rant

I hope it helps at least one person see the benefits of accessibility.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize the importance of "accessibility"! From a legal point of view as well as from a user experience point of view! I couldn't get a better answer! Thanks a lot! I'm gonna start planning this!

Comment: Graham, could you update this to remove/amend the reference to the accepted answer - your answer now _is_ the accepted answer, so the reference is out of date.

Comment: Wow! what an eye opener. Kudos to you Sir.

Comment: Not saying your wrong except for `that means that up to 28% of your user base could require larger text in order to see your App clearly.` Most people who are vision impaired in non-thirdworld-countries are people who wear glasses or contacts. I'm extremely vision impaired, but with contacts I can read very small text as it corrects my vision to be perfect.

Comment: @IsaacCWay That is why I used "up to" & "could", in reality I normally work on a principle of 10%. There are still situations where you might still benefit (contacts hurting, lost or damaged glasses) so really the sentence needs an "at some point" adding to the end. I do agree that it is a tough one as I possibly could have over-stated the severity of the issue, but I was just using the numbers there, it would have been confusing if I had said 10% after saying 2.2 billion people. So essentially I **am** wrong , but hopefully the point of "it is more common than you think" is not lost!

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is to disable font scaling for Text like below which will make sure that your font size is not affected by Accessibility changes.

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```